# Update a Model Field when DetailView encounter. [Django]

Tags: python, django, url

I have a DetailView something like in *views.py*:

**views.py**

```
class CustomView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'content'
    model = models.AppModel
    template_name = 'dynamictemplate.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(CustomView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        <...snipped...>
        return data
```

How could I update the model field, an `IntegerField` when the request from *urls.py* transfers to *views.py*. Let's suppose the name of IntegerField is **clicks** and when a user visits a particular link or passively, a model object from database, then how could I increment the **clicks** field of that object by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.object` and update it this way:

```
self.object.clicks = self.object.clicks + 1
self.object.save()
```

But as Daniel said in comment, using this code you can faced [race condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f). So it would be better to use [`F expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(CustomView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    self.object.clicks = F('clicks') + 1
    self.object.save()
    <...snipped...>
    return data
```

Comment: Be careful of race conditions here; it's possible for another thread to update the same db row before this one. It would be better to use an `F()` object to tell the db to do an atomic update.

Comment: It gave me output as a string "F('clicks') +  Value(1)". However, the value was successfully incremented by 1. Your previous answer worked fine for me.

Comment: can i use this method to update content, if then how?

Answer (score 0):

neverwalkaloner is very close, but the object needs to be refreshed from the database after it's saved.

```py
from django.db.models import F

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CustomView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    self.object.clicks = F('clicks') + 1
    self.object.save()
    self.object.refresh_from_db()
    <...snipped...>
    return context
```

Now the value of the clicks will be displayed instead of the `__repr__` of the F expression.